# can't access SDCARD at the starting time of device in livewallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

wallpaper in that i am showing data from database, which is actually in SDCARD

-so first if i want to access data from sdcard i have put some condition

```
       if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
```

it's working fine, now when i restart my device, at the startup time of my device, my wallpaper is want to access database, so it will first check above condition, but it will return **FALSE**

**May be SDCARD is mounted after some time of starting of ANDROID OS...**

so can anybody suggest me how to resolve that issue, because of large size of database i have to put it on SDCARD

Comment: All necessary read/write permissions granted in AndroidManifest?

Comment: I think it is because sdcard needs to be mounted after reboot.
It makes media scan on sdcard.
You can trick user by storing current used wallpaper in internal storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May be SDCARD is mounted after some time of starting of ANDROID OS

Yes Right, so register `action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` BroadcastReceiver to get broadcast when sd-card is  mounted.

First Register BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
  <receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:name=".ExternalStorageInfoReceiver">
    <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/> 
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

In ExternalStorageInfoReceiver do your work inside onReceive method:

```
public class ExternalStorageInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //change wallpaper here....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is stored on External storage then you should provide following intent filter,

```
<receiver android:name=".YourBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>                
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />                
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

See [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).